# Given sets $X,Y$, is it possible to find sets $X',Y'$ such that $X',X$ and $Y',Y$ are equinumerous, $X'\cap Y'=X'\cap X=Y'\cap Y=\emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary sets. Assuming the axioms of ZFC, is it true that there are sets $X'$ and $Y'$ such that $X'$ and $X$ have the same cardinal number, $Y'$ and $Y$ have the same cardinal number, $X\cap X'=\emptyset$, $Y\cap Y'=\emptyset$ and $X'\cap Y'=\emptyset$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

First let $X_0=\{X\}\times X$ and $Y_0=\{Y\}\times Y$, and use the axiom of regularity to show that $X_0\cap X=\varnothing=Y_0\cap Y$. (Clearly $|X_0|=|X|$ and $|Y_0|=|Y|$.) Then let $X'=\{0\}\times X_0$ and $Y'=\{1\}\times Y_0$; clearly $X'\cap Y'=\varnothing$, $|X'|=|X|$, and $|Y'|=|Y|$. Finally, use regularity again to show that $X'\cap X=\varnothing=Y'\cap Y$.